# HTML. changing one form field when another is changed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am still a beginner but I am guessing I need to use Javascript to do this? Can it be done with pure html?

This is what I want to accomplish:
Upon the field of “ID” change.
The value of the email” will automatically be generated by adding the suffix
of @gmail.ca.

Comment: Yes this requires JavaScript.  I'll show you an example in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this (written in pure Javascript):

```
document.getElementById("input").onkeydown = function () {
    var j = document.getElementById("email");
    j.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value + "@gmail.ca";
}
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zscw6y3u/).

*Here's a little explanation of what's going on (for learning purposes):*

In the HTML, there's an `input` and a `div`. In Javascript, an `onkeydown` listener is set for the `input` text field. This means the function will be called after every keystroke.

Then, the `innerHTML` of the `div` is updated with the `input` `value` with "gmail.ca" appended to the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this answer since it uses pure JS which best fits the users experience.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done with jQuery or pure JS.

HTML:

```
<input id="ID" type="text"></input>
<br>
<label id="email"></label>
```

JS:

```
$("#ID").keyup (function () {
    $("#email").text($("#ID").val() + '@gmail.ca');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uy57p5z/).